# What are these types of images called? illustration with notation?

Tags: word-usage, terminology

Is this type of images (img_1) called **sketch map with notation**?

[image]

while this type of images (img_2)  called **physical map without notation**?

[image]

while this type of images (img_3)  called **physical map with notation**?

[image]

Comment: “Map” is not a commonly used word at all in this context. You will have some difficulty getting the way you have used it to match up to any of the listed meanings for “map”. What made you use this word?  The first might more idiomatically be simply called a “sketch” or a “diagram” or even a “picture”.  The rest are “images”, “photos” or “pictures”. A more likely way to say an image is “with notation” is to say it is “labeled”.

Comment: @OrbitalAussie Thanks. Per you comments, img_1 is a labeled sketch, img_2 is just an image,  img_3 is a labeled image, right?

Comment: I would say the first one is a **drawing of a box**. Not sketch, not diagram and not picture. sketches are done by hand. diagrams involve numbers or math. And picture is too general. Also, notations is not right. Those are **descriptions in text boxes**. The others are just pictures, like you take with a camera.

Answer (score -1):

All three are images so I would avoid "image" when trying to distinguish them. I would call the first one a 'diagram with explanatory notes."

Here is a definition of diagram: "a graphic design that explains rather than represents
especially : a drawing that shows arrangement and relations (as of parts)."

https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/diagram

I would not call it a sketch, which means "a rough drawing representing the chief features of an object or scene and often made as a preliminary study."

https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/sketch

It is not that "sketch" is wrong; it is merely that "diagram" is a better fit for what is being mentioned.

The other two images appear to be photographs rather than diagrams or sketches. For the third, I might say "photograph with with added explanatory markings and notes."

Comment: I'd shorten the first one to simply an "annotated diagram".

Comment: Yes, that’s good too.